# Error while trying to allocate memory using malloc for custom struct

Tags: c, memory-management, malloc

I am attempting to allocate some dynamic memory for a custom stack in my c program. However, I receive the error 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000014 during the malloc call.

Here is my struct definition and my function calling malloc:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define EMPTY -1;

typedef enum boolean_tag { TRUE, FALSE } Boolean;
typedef enum direction_tag { ACROSS, DOWN } AnswerDirection;    /*The direction of an answer in the crossword*/

typedef struct answer_tag {
    /*A single 'Answer' is a single node making up a linked list*/
    int answerNumber;
    AnswerDirection direction;
    char *answerString;         /*The answer's value in chars*/
    struct answer_tag *nextAnswer;      /*Points to the next answer in the linked list*/
} Answer;

typedef struct space_tag {
    /*A single space inside of a board*/
    int numberOfCurrentAnswers; /*How many Answers currently cross through the space*/
    char value;
    int x;
    int y;
    struct space_tag *behindSpace;
    struct space_tag *nextSpace;
} Space;

    void InitAnswers(Answer *);
    Space *InitCrossword();
    Space *InitSpace();
    void ProgramClosingCleaning(Space *);

main(){
Space *board;
board = InitCrossword();
ProgramClosingCleaning(board);
}

void InitAnswers(Answer *answerKey){

}

Space *InitCrossword(){
int xLimit, yLimit;         /*Limits set*/
int xTraverse, yTraverse;   /*Coordinate variables to use in traversing*/
Space *currentSpace = NULL;
Space *nextSpace;           
printf("Please enter the size of the board: x y\n");
scanf("%d %d", &xLimit, &yLimit);
for (xTraverse = 0; xTraverse < xLimit; xTraverse++){
    for (yTraverse = 0; yTraverse < yLimit; yTraverse++){
        nextSpace = InitSpace();
        nextSpace->x = xTraverse;
        nextSpace->y = yTraverse;
        nextSpace->numberOfCurrentAnswers = 0;
        nextSpace->value = EMPTY;
        nextSpace->behindSpace = currentSpace;
        currentSpace->nextSpace = nextSpace;
        currentSpace = nextSpace;
    }
}
while (currentSpace->behindSpace != NULL)
    currentSpace = currentSpace->behindSpace;
return currentSpace;
}

Space *InitSpace(){
return (Space *) malloc(sizeof(Space));
}

void ProgramClosingCleaning(Space *currentSpace){
Space *nextSpace;
while (currentSpace != NULL){
    nextSpace = currentSpace->nextSpace;
    free(currentSpace);
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Can you post a small program that reproduces this?

Comment: It appears that your heap has been corrupted by something earlier. Also, it seems that you're running on Windows (by the error code); I;m not exactly sure, but I think that Windows may have some particular requirements/expectations on the stack being used by a thread. I'm not sure whether or not you can just set the stack for a thread to some arbitrary block of memory.

Comment: I posted a sample program. Yes, I am running windows.

Comment: @atob I think you're trying to write something to the `lastSpace` before assigning valid memory to it. `lastSpace` is at an offset of 20 (or 0x00000014) from the beginning of the struct. Also, posting code that doesn't even compile is not of any help.

Comment: Hi atob, welcome to Stack Overflow. By the way, you would have found your bug right away using the clang static analyzer. (It actually finds three bugs in your code, only one of which is the answer given by hmjd.) [Check it out yourself](http://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/) to find the other two.

Comment: Also, it might be a good idea to read the meta thread about posting homework on Stack Overflow: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-to-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two problems with the posted code (which the compiler should have emitted warnings for):

- Implicit declaration of `Init()` and `InitSpace()` which means they will have a return type of `int`
- `Init()` does not return a value.

---

The problem is this line in `InitCrossword()` function:

```
currentSpace->nextSpace = nextSpace;
```

on first iteration of the `for` loop `currentSpace` is NULL.

Comment: I just posted stub code. I have the rest of the information in my actual program.

Comment: You solved it, thanks a lot. I've been working on this for a long time!

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure the syntax you're using creates your struct with type `space_tag` and `Space` is actually a variable (see http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/structures/).

Try this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Space {
    int numberOfCurrentAnswers;
    char value;
    int x;
    int y;
    struct Space *lastSpace;
    struct Space *nextSpace;
};

main(){
    struct Space *space;
    space = Init();
}

Space *Init(){
    struct Space *nextSpace;
    nextSpace = InitSpace();
}

Space *InitSpace(){
    return (Space *) malloc(sizeof(Space));
}
```

Edited based on example code posted

Comment: You code generated an error, so I added struct in front of space_tag: return (struct space_tag *) malloc(sizeof(struct space_tag)); It still generated the same error

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the return function in `Init();`